# Angular 2+ and asp.net core server rendering

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-universal

I need some guidance on rendering server with angular 2+ and .net core, I have been doing some investigation about it and found some helpful information: Angular universal is the project for this matter:

[Angular 2 Server Rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wvZ7gakqV4)

I found a great example on how to apply angular universal and .net core on this repo: [MarkPieszak repository](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal). Please have a look to the controller and the way is implemented.

On the other hand I found another way to render in the server side using MVC views as per posted by MVP Damien:

Blog: [USING ANGULAR IN AN ASP.NET CORE VIEW WITH WEBPACK](https://damienbod.com/2017/05/02/using-angular-in-an-asp-net-core-view-with-webpack/)

Repo: [damienbod/AspNetCoreMvcAngular](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreMvcAngular)

Both are using webpack and .net core. I just want to ask which approach is better and cleaner. The advantages and disadvantages on each of them. I feel is easier to implement Damien approach based on controller code, but there is no angular universal implementation which I believe may have some drop backs.

Comment: after 7 months do you have any feedback?